# std::string to const char * error while creating new files

Tags: c++

We are trying to create multiple files on c++ but everytime we call the function in use it overwrites the file. we are trying to put a variable into the file name however the following error keeps happening.

```
string k= asctime(timeinfo);
string e= "/local/"+k+".csv";

fp = fopen(e, "w");
```

Error: No suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists in "main.cpp"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `fopen` takes `const char *`

```
fp = fopen(e, "w");
```

use `e.c_str()` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should call `c_str()`:

```
fp = fopen(e.c_str(), "w");
```